# strange behavior from textshop

Tags: texshop

Strange behavior from my Texshop: The code is perfectly compilable, I tested it on overleaf.But my Texshop is having a fist and gave me this weird output: [image]
Can anyone tell me what is going on here?

**Edit**: I am using Texshop 4.27 on Macbook Pro Catalina. Sorry I seem unable to reproduce the problem. I will update here if I encountered the same problem again. (I restarted Texshop and it seems to be doing fine.  Very strange.

Comment: Any idea on how to reproduce the behaviour?

Comment: What operation system and which version of it are you using? What version of TeXshop are you using?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: The current version of TeXShop is 4.44. Do consider performing an update.